# TypeError: Column is not iterable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
s = ["abcd:{'name':'john'}","defasdf:{'num':123}"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(s, "string").toDF("request")
display(df)
```

```text
+--------------------+
|             request|
+--------------------+
|abcd:{'name':'john'}|
| defasdf:{'num':123}|
+--------------------+
```

I would like to get as

```text
+--------------------+---------------+
|             request|            sub|
+--------------------+---------------+
|abcd:{'name':'john'}|{'name':'john'}|
| defasdf:{'num':123}|    {'num':123}|
+--------------------+---------------+
```

I did write as below, but it is throwing error :

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

```
df = df.withColumn("sub",substring(col('request'),locate('{',col('request')),length(col('request'))-locate('{',col('request'))))
df.show()
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`substring`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#substring) function in SQL expression in order to pass columns for `position` and `length` arguments. Note also that you need to add `+1` to length to get correct result:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "json",
    F.expr("substring(request, locate('{',request), length(request) - locate('{', request) + 1)")
)

df.show()
#+--------------------+---------------+
#|             request|           json|
#+--------------------+---------------+
#|abcd:{'name':'john'}|{'name':'john'}|
#| defasdf:{'num':123}|    {'num':123}|
#+--------------------+---------------+
```

You could also consider using `regexp_extract` function instead of substring like this:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "json",
    F.regexp_extract("request", "^.*:(\\{.*\\})$", 1)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But why can't I use outside of SQL expression??

Comment: @subro That's a constraint of  the DataFrame API pyspark function [susbstring](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#substring) which is defined like this.